# How to connect from Advance Rest Client to Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I have used the below url to connect to server from Advanced Rest Client
**http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/api/2.0/auth/signin**

I get the error

Requested Url cannot be reached. How to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you paste that URL in a browser? I have a guess what's causing the problem but need to know what the browser does first.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the REST API to use depends on the version of Tableau Server that is in use, and so I suspect that you're trying to use the wrong API version. Try the following link for more information:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_versions.htm